# Unknown property 'VfSearchController.article'

Tags: apex, visualforce, knowledge

I am using chapter 3 in [Salesforce Knowledge
Developer Guide
Version 34.0, Summer ’15](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_dev_guide.pdf)
 as a starting point to build a Knowledge search page.

> Our data category hierarchy is: Topics > Product Name > Tabs in
>   Product

I want the top part of the page to show the typical search results and a bottom table that shows related articles according the data category "Topics".

Has anyone tried anything like this? Have any suggestions? I am new to VF and Apex so any help would be immensely appreciated.

EDIT**
I was unable to post the VF & apex code as a reference in this rtf box. Here is a link to the Success Community that has all the code snippets. [Unknown property 'VfSearchController.article'](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?criteria=BESTANSWERS&feedtype=RECENT#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=All&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=90630000000DG4gAAG)